# C# Code writes multiple lines instead on one new line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have encountered a problem where my C# code used to write lines to a text file writes more than one line of one type. For instance, I want it to save test3, 100 to a text file containing:

test1, 10

test2, 75

instead of getting

test1, 10

test2, 75

test3, 100

I get:

test1, 10

test2, 75

test3, 100

test3, 100

and so for more than 100 more lines.

Comment: The naive answer is that you're either calling the method more than once, or the text you're writing contains multiple lines. Have you verified that you're not doing any of those?

Comment: What calls this code? The issue does not appear to be in the code you've posted.

Comment: Side note: You should be using `StreamWriter`s in `using` blocks. Also, you can just use something like `File.AppendText` and do away with all of that extra `StreamWriter` code.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I have updated the Code with the calling method

Comment: How many times is `SaveUsername` being subscribed to the onClick listener?

Comment: It looks like you add a subscription to the event every time you call your `UpdateUI` which means that the additional lines you output increases with every `UpdateUI`.

Comment: Am I missing something?  I see no code

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you're likely entering the `else if (pacManLives == 0)` block multiple times. This is adding duplicate listeners, thereby calling your save method more than once later on.

You should probably be adding your listeners in some initialization code that gets called one time only.

Comment: What do you mean by "paused"? If your code ever adds multiple listeners to a single event, they'll all be called once that even fired. You probably don't want to be doing that.